# Unwind with more than 1 segue using iOS 7 UIViewController transition animations

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, ios7, segue

I am using the UIViewController animated transitions introduced in iOS7. I am able to produce some really great transitions going back and forth between VC's using segues etc.

Take a look at my picture below:

[image]

I can very easily go back and forth if it is just one segue/vc at a time. For example if, I go from Screen 1 to Screen 2, the animation works perfect. And then say I go back to 1 or forward to 3, it works perfectly.

But, if you notice on screen 4 at the bottom there is a button that says "Back To Screen 1"—this is an unwinding segue to screen 1. The issue is, I can't get the transition animation to work. In fact, the delegate methods never get called.

Here is how I have it set up (for example animating from screen 2 to 3):

```
//This is found in screen 2's view controller .m

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"screen2to3"]) {

        UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.transitioningDelegate = self;
        destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

    }
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {

    STSlideAnimation *animator = [STSlideAnimation new];
    animator.presenting = YES;
    return animator;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {

    STSlideAnimation *animator = [STSlideAnimation new];
    return animator;
}

//This is the unwinding segue action

-(IBAction)returnToScreen2:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

}
```

This works perfect going both to screen3 and back to screen2. The animation gets called both ways. However, I can't get any animation to work when going back more than one vc at a time. Any ideas? Let me know if I need to post more sample code.

Comment: If you are doing fullScreen transition no need for `destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;`, try `destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;` instead...

Comment: @MikePollard Actually, if you look at the sample code that is available (and if I'm not mistaken, Apple's own example code) it is necessary to set the modalTransitionStyle to custom, thus it knows to look for a transitioningDelegate etc.

Comment: No, this is not true. You can quite happily provide a transitioningDelegate for FullScreen modal presentations. The difference between UIModalPresentationCustom & UIModalPresentationFullScreen is that when using UIModalPresentationCustom the presenting viewController is not removed and can be seen 'behind' the presented viewController after the transition ends.

Comment: @MikePollard You're right. I just tested it. However, this does nothing to change or address my issue.

Comment: Does your screen 4 prepare for segue method have the relevant code to set the transitioningDelegate during the unwind segue?

Comment: @MikePollard I believe so. No matter what I have tried, it won't even try to animate from 4 back to 1. However, 4 will go back to 3 without any hitch. I believe the issue lies in the fact that there is a hierarchy of modally presented controllers. If they are traversing one at a time, there is no issue, but when traversing multiples, it seems to ignore the animation code.

Comment: Interesting ... I wonder if the same problem exists with custom transitions within a UINavigationController, which looks quite suited to you 'stack' of view controllers you're trying to achieve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46868/discussion-between-davemac-and-mike-pollard)

Comment: @daveMac did you ever solve this issue? I've been able to get limited success by putting a dismissViewController:animated call into the root VC's unwind catcher, but it still seems to call animations on all the inbetweens as well and it flashes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **make custom segue classes for each type of transition** you wish to apply

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end


@implementation CustomSegue

 -(void)perform {

 // write your transition code here
 // this code will be called every time transition is made

}
```

Select a segue in storybord - in inspector change its type to custom - select custom class you have made in above case "CustomSegue"

If you have subclassed it properly then you will find inspector as below


[image: Segue Inspector]

Unwind as usual but will get the same effect even if you have poped from 4th controller to 1st controller

Comment: I'm not sure that you can write transition code there. I have seen that on several different posts online, but when I implemented it myself, I found that they caused issues with the VC's not working correctly. Furthermore, if you can simply do your transition animation code in the segues, why did Apple introduce the view controller transitions in iOS 7?

Comment: Let me further clarify what I mean, there are many, many tutorials out there that show you how to write custom animation segues. The issue is that there are unwanted side effects. Take a look at this tutorial and scroll down to the comments to see what I am referring to: http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/comment-page-1/#comment-479