# Issue when unwinding with custom transition manager

Tags: swift, ios8

I built a custom transition manager to deal with moving views around spatially in my app.

I have three view controllers: `MainViewController`, `PastSessionsViewController` and `JournalViewController`.

My problem is: When the user goes from Main to Past Sessions to Journal and presses "Done" in Journal to back to Main, the view jumps immediately to Past Sessions before Main zooms in from the right.

The intended behavior is for Main to push in from the left side of the screen and push Journal off the right side of the screen.

I added a line break in `animationControllerForDismissedController` and noticed that `dismissed.description` is `PastSessionsViewController` when it should be `JournalViewController` when moving from Journal to Main after pressing "Done".

I'm not sure why that is. I have the unwind segues wired up correctly and my code in `prepareForSegue` in `JournalViewController` makes sense.  I don't believe I should need to define the dismissing view controller, this should be handled for me like it is in every other transition.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this so that Past Sessions doesn't jump back into the user's view before the transition, that'd be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

**TransitionManager.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning , UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    var presenting = true
    var direction = "down" //from the top. accepts up/down/left/right

    // transition between pressing "Begin" and the water beginning to fill
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.8
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        var offScreenTop: CGAffineTransform
        var offScreenBottom: CGAffineTransform

        switch self.direction {
        case "up" :
            offScreenTop = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, container.frame.height)
            offScreenBottom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -container.frame.height)

            toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenTop : offScreenBottom

            container.addSubview(fromView)
            container.addSubview(toView)
        case "left" :
            // TODO: rename top/bottom/l/r
            offScreenTop = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)
            offScreenBottom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)

            toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenTop : offScreenBottom

            container.addSubview(fromView)
            container.addSubview(toView)
        case "right" :
            offScreenTop = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)
            offScreenBottom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)

            toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenTop : offScreenBottom

            container.addSubview(fromView)
            container.addSubview(toView)
        default:
            // down
            offScreenTop = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -container.frame.height)
            offScreenBottom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, container.frame.height)

            toView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenTop : offScreenBottom

            container.addSubview(toView)
            container.addSubview(fromView)
        }

        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                fromView.transform = self.presenting ? offScreenBottom : offScreenTop
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: {
                finished in transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }

    // return the animator when presenting a viewcontroller
    // rememeber that an animator (or animation controller) is any object that adheres to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol
    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = true

        return self
    }

    // return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = false

        return self
    }
}
```

**JournalViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class JournalViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {    
    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()

    var journalEntryCoreDataLocation: Int?
    var journalEntryToEdit: String?
    var journalEntryToEditTimestamp: NSDate?

    @IBOutlet weak var journalEntryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var journalEntryTextArea: UITextView!

    @IBAction func doneJournalEntry(sender: AnyObject) {
        journalEntryTextArea.resignFirstResponder()

        // do some stuff in coredata
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        journalEntryTextArea.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
        destinationVC.showJournalButton = false

        let transitionManager = self.transitionManager
        transitionManager.presenting = true
        transitionManager.direction = "left"
//        transitionManager.animationControllerForDismissedController(JournalViewController)

        destinationVC.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
    }
}
```

Comment: The conventional wisdom seems to be that one cannot use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`-based transitions for unwind segues. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21540461/1271826 or http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/03/ios-unwind-segue-custom-animation/.

Comment: I played around with this a bit and see the same behavior you describe. My only successful work-around was to take a snapshot of the view in `prepareForSegue` and then change the `animateTransition` to (a) hide the "from" view; (b) add an image view with the snapshot image; (c) animate this image view; and (d) when complete, remove the image view and snapshot. Pretty darn ugly. There's got to be a better way to do this with `animateTransition`!